# Issue while saving Non-English character

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, utf-8

We are working with one application where we need to save data in language `Gujarati`.

Technologies used in Applcation is listed below.

- Spring MVC Version 4.1.6.RELEASE
- Hibernate Version 4.3.5.Final
- MySQL 6.0.11

My JSP is configured with

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

And

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Hibernate configuration is

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
```

MySQL URL is

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbName?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8
```

Pojo having `String` field to store that data.

MySQL have `VARCHAR` datatype to store data with **charset=utf8** and **Collation=utf8_general_ci**

When i tried to save any non-english(Gujrati) character it show some garbage character like `àª?à«?àª?` for "ગુજ".

Is there any other configuration which i missed here.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to save through a JSP page. Did you do request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") or something similar, before processing the request? Can you experiment saving through a unit test?

Comment: Yes, for testing purpose i created Filter with url pattern /* and write request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")  in it. in this case it converts all characters to ? (question marks).

Comment: Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...`.  This will help me diagnose whether it was inserted correctly but read incorrectly, or vice versa.

Comment: If you see question marks as many as your characters it might be ok but you can be more sure inspecting the characters after changing debugger font. Alternatively you can check the byte values that you obtain by string.getBytes().

Comment: @Rick: HEX(col) results C3A0C2AAC297C3A0C2ABC281C3A0C2AAC29C for ગુજ.

Comment: Have you been able to identify if it's a storing problem, or it's being stored properly, but is a display issue?

Comment: you should have your project, your POM.xml, your JSP, and DB set in UTF-8, then you wont have problems. If that's what you want, let me know, I will tell you where all to set, except MySQL, I know about Postgres rather than mysql.

Comment: If you are using Apache tomcat, then in Connector also you have to specify UTF-8 like URIEncoding="utf-8". Bol dena code chahiye to.

Comment: Where do you see those characters, while displaying them on a JSP, MySQL terminal or somewhere else on an I/O device? The later two cases might not support the UTF-8 character encoding or not configured to use it. If it is the **only** case, then it has whatsoever nothing to do with JSP/Spring (MVC)/Hibernate or even the container in use. (Aside from the concrete problem : UTF-8 in MySQL uses 1 to 3 bytes. It is not fully qualified to be UTF-8. If you need 4-byte character set anyway, you will need `utf8mb4` which is only available, since MySQL 5.5.3).

Comment: did you debug along the pipe? Where does the issue occur? How does the code used for saving data looks like?

Answer (score 7):

I was facing the same problem while inserting "**tamil**" characters into the database.After surfing a lot I got a better and working solution and it solves my problem.Here I am sharing my solution with you.I hope it will help you to clear your doubts regarding that Non English character.

```
INSERT INTO 
STUDENT(name,address) 
VALUES 
(N'பெயர்', N'முகவரி');
```

I am using a sample since you have not provided me any structure of your table and field name.

Comment: This does not really anyswer the question.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you want `ગુજ` (GA JA with Vowel sign U)?

I think you somehow specified "latin5".  (Yes I see you have UTF-8 everywhere, but "latin5" is the only way I can make things work.)

```
CONVERT(CONVERT(UNHEX('C3A0C2AAC297C3A0C2ABC281C3A0C2AAC29C')
       USING utf8) USING latin5) = 'ગુજ'
```

Plus you ended up with "double encoding"; I suspect this is what happened:

- The client had characters encoded as utf8 (good); and
- `SET NAMES latin5` was used, but it lied by claiming that the client had latin5 encoding; and
- The column in the table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (good).

If possible, it would be better to start over -- empty the tables, be sure to have `SET NAMES utf8` or establish utf8 when connecting from your client to the database.  Then repopulate the tables.

If you would rather try to recover the existing data, this *might* work:

```
UPDATE ... SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(
                         CONVERT(UNHEX(col) USING utf8)
                         USING latin5)) USING utf8);
```

But you would need to do that for each messed up column in each table.

A partial test of that code is to do

```
SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(CONVERT(
                         CONVERT(UNHEX(col) USING utf8)
                         USING latin5)) USING utf8)
     FROM table;
```

I say "partial test" because `looking` right may not prove that `is` right.

After the `UPDATE`, `SELECT HEX(col)` get `E0AA97E0AB81E0AA9C` for `ગુજ`.  Note that *most* Gujarati hex should be of the form `E0AAyy` or `E0AByy`.  You might also find `20` for a blank space.

I apologize for not being more certain.  I have been tackling Character Set issues for a decade, but this is a new variant.

Comment: P.S.  I failed to solve it faster because I was seeing `àªà«àª`, which did not quite agree with your `àª?à«?àª?`.  I still can't explain that part.  But it should not matter; the HEX is more definitive.

Comment: Tried your solutions,It will not work for me. It seems like I missed something on my configuration side.

Comment: In your "MySQL url" you have only the _outbound_ setting (`&characterSetResults=utf8`).  I don't know what _should_ be there, but perhaps it is  `characterEncoding=UTF-8`

Answer (score 4):

There might be a couple of things that you could have missed out. I had the same problem with mysql on linux, what I had to do is to edit `my.cnf` like this:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8

[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8
```

For e.g. on Centos this file is location at `/etc/my.cnf` on Windows (my pc) `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini`. Please note that `ProgramData` might be hidden.

Also the other thing if you are using Tomcat is that you have to sepcify UTF-8 for URI encoding. Just edit `server.xml` and modify your main `Connector` element:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Also make sure you added character encoding filter in your application:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "CharacterEncodingFilter", urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class CharacterEncodingFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig)
            throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Another tip, don't lean only on setting the `characterEncoding` as a hibernate property `<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>`, make sure you add it explicitely as connection variable on the DB url, so

`jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbName?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8`

Also, as there is some many layers where an encoding would be lost, you can try to isolate the layer and update to a question. E.g. if its upon storing to DB, or at some point before

Answer (score 2):

Your applicationContext file should be like this:

To make Spring MVC application supports the internationalization, register two beans :

1. SessionLocaleResolver
   Register a “SessionLocaleResolver” bean, named it exactly the same characters “localeResolver“. It resolves the locales by getting the predefined attribute from user’s session.
   Note
   If you do not register any “localeResolver”, the default AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver will be used, which resolves the locale by checking the accept-language header in the HTTP request.
2. LocaleChangeInterceptor
   Register a “LocaleChangeInterceptor” interceptor and reference it to any handler mapping that need to supports the multiple languages. The “paramName” is the parameter value that’s used to set the locale.

   ```
   <bean id="localeResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
       <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
       <property name="paramName" value="language" />
   </bean>

   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
       <property name="interceptors">
          <list>
           <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
          </list>
       </property>
   </bean>

   <!-- Register the bean -->
   <bean class="com.common.controller.WelcomeController" />

   <!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
   <bean id="messageSource"
       class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
       <property name="basename" value="welcome" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
       <property name="prefix">
           <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
       </property>
       <property name="suffix">
           <value>.jsp</value>
       </property>
   </bean>
   ```

The native2ascii is a handy tool build-in in the JDK, which is used to convert a file with ‘non-Latin 1′ or ‘non-Unicode’ characters to ‘Unicode-encoded’ characters.

Native2ascii example

1. Create a file (source.txt)

Create a file named “source.txt”, put some Chinese characters inside, and save it as “UTF-8″ format.

2. native2ascii

Use native2ascii command to convert it into Unicode format.

C:>native2ascii -encoding utf8 c:\source.txt c:\output.txt

The native2ascii will read all the characters from “c:\source.txt” and encode it with “utf8″ format, and output all encoded characters to “c:\output.txt”

3. Read Output

Open the “c:\output.txt”, you will see the all encoded characters, e.g \ufeff\u6768\u6728\u91d1

welcome.properties

welcome.springmvc = \u5feb\u4e50\u5b66\u4e60

> Call the above string and store the value in database.

And if you want to display that inside JSP page:

> Remember add the line
>
> “<%@ page contentType=”text/html;charset=UTF-8″ %>”
>
> on top of the jsp page, else the page may not able to display the UTF-8
>   (Chinese) characters properly.